# How to use Android studio to compile an apex(Android Pony EXpress)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

We have an apex(Android Pony EXpress) and only rely on Android public api. At present, we want to generate this apex by independent compilation instead of compiling with Android source code. Can we compile an apex independently through Android studio?
If not, is it possible to solve this problem through gradle and other means?